# How to update new column using only substring after specified text - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull only part of the value from one column: "CI_Support_Remarks" to update another column "Asset_Number" in my table "CI_Information". If the data is currently stored as:

"Asset #: 33800000125Primary support:Persons nameSecondary support....ect"

"word word word Asset #: 338000000152Primary support:Persons nameSecondary support....ect"

How do I only pull the number following "Asset #:" and nothing else to update the Asset Number column. I am only trying to update the Asset column and not affect the CI_Support_Remarks column.

The length of each Asset # is 11 digits.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the number always has the same length, then this is easy:

```
update CI_Information
    set AssetNumber = left(substring_index(CI_Support_Remarks, 'Asset#: ', -1), 11)
    where CI_Support_Remarks like '%Asset#: %';
```